# How to add time and replace it in a file in Perl?

Tags: perl

i have wriiten the following code to fetch date from server and to display it in yy/mm/dd-hh/mm/ss format.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
system(`date '+ %Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S' >ex.txt`);
open(MYINPUTFILE, "/tmp/ranjan/ex.txt");
while(<MYINPUTFILE>)
{
    chomp;
    print "$_\n";
}
close(MYINPUTFILE);
```

output:

```
2013/07/29-18:58:04
```

I want to add two minutes to the time and need to replace the time present in a                file, Pls give me some ideas.

Comment: Instead of `system`, use `$a=qx( date '+...')` and then (assuming it is needed for some other process) write `$a` to the file.  Don't use bare file handles; use `open my $f, $path, $mode` instead.  Don't `chop` a variable if you are just going to append a newline to it.  Don't use human readable timestamps: use epoch times instead.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: don't use an external command just to get the current time in *any* format

Comment: Please xplain better what you want to do. Is it to modify a file that contains a date/time to advance that time by two minutes? Or do you want to print the current time plus two minutes to the console? Or write it to a file?

Answer (score 4):

Change your date command to add the 2 minutes:

```
date --date "+2 min" '+ %Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S'
```

or a Perl version:

```
use POSIX;
print strftime("%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S", localtime(time + 120));
```

Answer (score 3):

It is best to use [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) to do the parsing and formatting of dates. It is a built-in module and shoudln't need installation.

Unusually, in this case the replacement date/time string is exactly the same length as the original string read from the file, so the modification can be done in-place. Normally the overall length of a file changes, so it is necessary either to create a new file and delete the old one, or to read the entire file into memory and write it out again.

This program opens the file for simultaneous read/write, reads the first line from the file, parses it using `Time::Piece`, adds two minutes (120 seconds), seeks to the start of the file again, and prints the new date/time reformatted in the same way as the original back to the file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Time::Piece;
my $format = '%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S';

open my $fh, '+<', 'ex.txt';

my $date_time = <$fh>;
chomp $date_time;
$date_time = Time::Piece->strptime($date_time, $format);

$date_time += 60 * 2;

seek $fh, 0, 0;
print $fh $date_time->strftime($format);
close $fh;
```

**output**

```
2013/07/29-19:00:04
```